# Jackson "MismatchedInputException: No Object Id found for an instance" when using @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

First of all, I'm trying to prevent recursion in JSON, when I'm getting `User` entity. To do this I've added `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation to my `User` class. It works as expected for serialization (when I get `User`), but on deserialization (on registering `User`) Jackson returns this:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No Object Id found for an instance of `.entity.User`, to assign to property 'id'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No Object Id found for an instance of `.entity.User`, to assign to property 'id'
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 13, column: 1]]
```

User.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
@Validated
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator::class, property = "id", scope = Int::class)
data class User(

        @field:Id
        @field:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Int,

        @Valid
        @Size(
                min = 4,
                message = "Username '\${validatedValue}' should be at least {min} characters long"
        )
        @NotEmpty(message = "asd")
        var username: String = "",

        ...

        @field:OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = true)
        var userInfo: UserInfo? = null

)
```

JSON I'm sending for deserialization (Works when `@JsonIdentityInfo` is removed):

```
{
    "username": "qwert",
    "password": "tyui",
    "email": "asdasd",
    "phone": ""
}
```

Method used for registration:

```
    @PostMapping("/users/signup")
    fun addUser(@RequestBody @Valid user: User): JSendResponse<Unit> {

        user.password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.password)
        userService.save(user)

        return JSendResponse(data = Unit)
    }
```

**UPD:**
The solution to this problem was to explicitly set `id` field in Json because it's generated on persistence level. But I don't want to set it explicitly, because frontend doesn't know the `id` of the new object.

Comment: What version of jackson-databind are you using?

Comment: It's 2.9.9.3 with jackson-core 2.9.9. Actually, I found a solution, but I'm not satisfied with it. Updated the question.

Comment: that seems to be a bug in some versions of jackson-databind https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1367

Comment: Now I'm using GraphQL on top of the repository layer and it's solving pretty much all of my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonIdentityInfo is used to avoid circular reference, that causes a stackoverflow. Jackson is supposed to assign an 'id' when it finds this type of references.

It seems some versions of jackson have a bug on this functionality: [github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1367](http://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1367)
So you should either try to change version of jackson, or do the following alternatives:

**Some alternatives are:**

**Use the annotations JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference** on the fields that reference each other; in your case, 'user' and 'userInfo'. JsonManagedReference is the side that gets (de)serialized normally. JsonBackReference is the back part of reference and won't be (de)serialized.
Make sure to set the 'back reference' part after deserialized.

If, for example, your UserInfo property is the managed ref, inside the User class, you should have the following results:

```
class User {
    Long id;
    @JsonManagedReference
    UserInfo userInfo;
}

class UserInfo {
    String nickname;
    String moto;
    @JsonBackReference
    User user;
    ...
}

// OUTPUT EXAMPLE
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo("johndoe","it works", null);
    User user = new User(1L, info);
    info.setUser(user);
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println("user = " + om.writeValueAsString(user));
    System.out.println("userinfo = " + om.writeValueAsString(info));
}
```

OUTPUT

```
user = {
   "id":1,
   "userInfo":{
     "nickname":"johndoe",
     "moto":"it works"
    }
}
userinfo = {
   "nickname":"johndoe",
   "moto":"it works"
}
```

Another alternatice is to **Create a custom serializer and a custom deserializer** for your entities. This is the most powerful way to (de)serialize; you can have both sides (de)serialized and even add custom properties.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = UserDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = UserSerializer.class)
data class User(
    ...
)
```

To create custom (de)serializers, you can follow these tutorials:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. `User` and `UserInfo` are bidirectional so when I request for `UserInfo` I also expect `User` in the response and vice versa. So JsonManagedReference does not solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I didn't write the complete answer, so I edited it, as well as included another, most powerful, alternative, which is to write custom (de)serializers

Comment: Not the best solution, but it works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching:

This issue may be caused when combining @JsonIdentityInfo.

---

In case you are using @JsonTypeInfo:

- use @JsonTypeName together with @JsonSubTypes
- wrap potential generic fields into a class extending from it's type

---

If you are using non-empty constructors:

- try using (private) empty ones annotated with @JsonCreator (especially in referenced classes) and assign any value to final attributes (which jackson will override nevertheless)

Jackson throws very unrelated and illogical exceptions that are caused trying to deserialize an instance inside of the exact same instance, seeing them as different objects.

---

Tested in java, but shouldn't differ